# 6 billion cannot be recognized as an integer in java?

Tags: java

I am having problems when I try to store `6000000000` in an `int` variable.

This is the part of script I am having problems with:

```
Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter a number here:");
int k = x.nextInt();
System.out.println(k);
```

When I input `6000000000` the output should be the same, but the output is this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException: For input string: "6000000000"
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
```

What is this? How to prevent this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The value is too big, java `int`s can only hold values from –2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.

Use a `long` instead.

Comment: and once `long` becomes too short, use a `double`

Comment: ... and once double becomes too short use a `BigInteger` :-)

Comment: ... and once `BigInteger` becomes too short, buy more RAM

Comment: @assylias: and once RAM becomes too short, just set the value to 42

Comment: I think somewhere between *home*'s and *assylias* suggestion, you should start thinking about why you need so large numbers... :P

Comment: to calculate graham's number maybe? :P just kidding i would need all the computing power on the earth and still not be able to get it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `long` and [`nextLong`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLong), your number is larger than [`Integer.MAX_INT`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE): `2^31 - 1`.

Also note that you can anticipate this error if you first test the stream using [`hasNextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) you can see that the maximum value for `int` is `2,147,483,647 = 2^31 - 1`. Try `long` instead:

```
long k = x.nextLong();
System.out.println(k);
```

`long` will take you up to `9,223,372,036,854,775,807 = 2^63 - 1`. Once you need values over that, you can either look into [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) (`Scanner#nextBigInteger()`) or just use a floating point number like `double` (`Scanner#nextDouble()`).

Answer (score 0):

or if you are using really big numbers (bigger than long) then use nextBigInteger